# /dev/disk/by-uuid not showing all disks

Tags: linux, hard-drive, xenserver, uuid

I am working with local storage repositories on an installation of XenServer and I am trying to use the UUID to delete a SR made in error.  When I look at the disks by-id here is the output:

```
[root@xenser111 lib]# ls -l /dev/disk/by-id

total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Jul 16 09:02 scsi-3600050e02e433200d7110000d6930000 -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jul 16 09:02 scsi-3600050e02e433200d7110000d6930000-part1 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jul 16 09:02 scsi-3600050e02e433200d7110000d6930000-part2 -> ../../sda2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jul 16 09:02 scsi-3600050e02e433200d7110000d6930000-part3 -> ../../sda3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Jul 16 09:02 scsi-SATA_SAMSUNG_HD103SJS2AEJ1BZ502526 -> ../../sdc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jul 19 04:15 scsi-SATA_SAMSUNG_HD103SJS2AEJ1BZ502526-part1 -> ../../sdc1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Jul 19 04:32 scsi-SATA_SAMSUNG_HD103SJS2AEJ1BZ502653 -> ../../sdb
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jul 19 04:32 scsi-SATA_SAMSUNG_HD103SJS2AEJ1BZ502653-part1 -> ../../sdb1
```

However, when I look at the disks by-uuid, it does not show /dev/sdb or /dev/sdc:

```
[root@xenser111 lib]# ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid/
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jul 16 09:02 b1341321-038d-43e6-a194-0c3598f47152 -> ../../sda1
```

Why is this happening?  Do I have to enact some command to populate the by-uuid directory?  And how else can I find the UUID?  (I have also used `blkid` to no use).

If it is relevant, /sda is a RAID 0.

Answer (score 2):

Are there file systems created on those partitions on sdc & sdb? Disks don't have UUID values, file systems do.

For example:

```
root@marvin:~# blkid /dev/sda
root@marvin:~# blkid /dev/sda1
/dev/sda1: UUID="8eb16c98-cf75-429b-af08-db29f5d5335b" TYPE="ext4"
```

Swap can also have a UUID:

```
root@marvin:~# blkid /dev/sda5
/dev/sda5: UUID="a1a91f5f-6d6a-4cf7-a133-afaafeb2eb1e" TYPE="swap" 
root@marvin:~#
```

Have you created valid File Systems on those partitions?

Comment: They are valid file systems but maybe I should try deleting and re-creating the partitions.